# How do I import an Excel Spreadsheet into a blog..?

Tags: excel

We are interested in trying to import an Excel spreadsheet into our Blog.

A sample of the Excel spreadsheet that we generate each day and want to export into our Blog is located at:

http://www.wallstreetsignals.com/WhatsWorking.html

Our Blog is located at:

http://whatsworkinginthestockmarket.blogspot.com/

We are interested in a program or method that would allow us to just import the Excel spreadsheet into our Blog  instead of having to hand input all the data, which is what we are doing now.

Thank you for your thoughts and the  cost to have you help accomplish our goal.

Philip
WallStreetSignals.com

Comment: Not programming related? Self-promotion?

Comment: Perhaps, but given that it's nofollowed, it's not going to get much traction here, and it's at least obliquely programming related, might as well leave it alone...

Answer (score 1):

Well, outside of creating a program (which is possible, using PHP, Perl, Java, etc and either an excel input module or converting to CSV or XML and processing that)...

Have you considered using Google Documents or another online spreadsheet software?  It's easy to import an excel spreadsheet, and then embed the spreadsheet in the blog post or webpage.  Then if you need to change it, modify the google document spreadsheet and the changes are rendered on the webpage or blog post immediately.

-Adam

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing might be to use Google Docs. Upload your spreadsheet, then publish from Google Docs to your blog. See [this article](http://lifehacker.com/366821/use-google-docs-to-publish-blog-entries).

Answer (score 1):

Can your blog consume XML? You can set up an XML Schema in Excel 2007 and just export it to an XML file.  You would need to write an XSLT.

I also have a macro that will write out XML to a file... can upload that if it would help...

Answer (score 0):

If your spreadsheet is generated by a macro, you could just modify a macro to generate html or some other sort of blog markup ready for copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Excel can save as HTML, which you could then strip the metadata from and use in your website.  Unfortunately the HTML that it generates is very bloated.  If you do not mind client lock-in, you could consider embedding the XLS file directly on your website, and having your viewers use the IE embedded excel viewer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ASP.NET you could use [SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) to load an Excel workbook, grab values, formatted values or even images to display on a web page. There are [live ASP.NET samples](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) with source if you want to check it out.

Disclaimer: I work for SpreadsheetGear LLC